# How can I let a while loop pause for a specified time (datetime)?

Tags: python, datetime, time, while-loop

I would like to let a while loop run, the stuff thats happening inside takes about 2 seconds to complete (it varies a small amount), so if I use time.sleep(60 or 58) it would still shift slightly. So what I would like to do is that the while loop starts for example at 16:00:00 (because I click run) and does its stuff, waits and then starts again at 16:01:00, so a minute later and so on. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Measure the time taken by the operation. Then subtract that from your loop period to get the amount of time to sleep.

```
import time

while True:
    start = time.time()
    # do your thing
    time.sleep(60 - (time.time() - start))
```

Answer (score 0):

Where are you putting time.sleep() in your code? Have you tried putting it at the end of the while loop when all of the processing is complete?

Comment: Yes I have, but the code sometimes takes 2 seconds to complete sometimes 1 second, so the time it starts the next time shifts around. And I want to have it started exactly a minute or so later, even when the code takes different times to complete the task.

Comment: Okay, I see what the issue is now. You're wanting to factor in elapsed run time to your time calculation to ensure it consistently hits exactly 1 minute?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).